# Selective drop down population in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am working on a rota based project for work and I am trying to get working a drop down menu that only selects certain entries based on criteria. Basically in A2 you enter a shift start time and in A3 you enter the shift end time. In A1 I want to have a drop down menu to only have the staff that are available for that shift. This would all be on sheet 1. On sheet 2 I have all the staff and their availabilties. Sheet 2 has all the details in seperate columns, so name is in column A, available from for Monday is in column B, available until for Monday is in column C and so on for the whole week. I have made a macro (shown below) that collects the names and I have tested it to see if it works (which it does). Is there a way to get the results of this macro to output into a drop down menu or is there a formula that can do it instead of using a macro. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Sub FridayShifts()

Dim StaffAvailabilty As Range                                       'Staff table'
Dim StaffName As Range                                              'Current staff row'
Dim StaffList As Collection                                         'Drop down list'
Dim StartTime As Double                                             'Start time'
Dim EndTime As Double                                               'End time'

Set StaffAvailabilty = Sheets("STAFF").Range("A2:Q42").Rows         'Create the staff table'
Set StaffList = New Collection                                      'Creates a new collection for drop down'
StartTime = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) * 86400                         'Gets the shift start time'
EndTime = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) * 86400                           'Gets the shift end time'

For Each StaffName In StaffAvailabilty                              'Run through each row on the table'
If IsEmpty(StaffName.Columns(1).Value) = False Then                 'If there is a name (check first column not empty)'
    If IsEmpty(StaffName.Columns(4).Value) = False Then             'If staff member is available (check fourth column has a value'
        If StaffName.Columns(4).Value * 86400 <= StartTime Then     'If staff start time is less or equal to shift start time'
            If StaffName.Columns(5).Value * 86400 >= EndTime Then   'If staff finish time is greater or equal to shift end time'
                StaffList.Add (StaffName.Columns(1).Value)          'Add the value to the drop down'
                MsgBox (StaffName.Columns(1).Value)                 'Test to display staff members is working'
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

MsgBox (StaffList.Count)                                            'Test to display total staff members is working'

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the question *How to make a DV from a Collection.*

Answer (score 1):

Replace `MsgBox (StaffList.Count)` with

```
ValidationFromCollection StaffAvailabilty, StaffList, StaffAvailabilty.Range("A1")
```

and use the next function:

```
Sub ValidationFromCollection(sh As Worksheet, collect As Collection, rngVal As Range)
  Dim lastCol As Long, El As Variant, i As Long
  i = 1

  lastCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
  For Each El In collect
    sh.Cells(i, lastCol).value = El
    i = i + 1
  Next
  With rngVal.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & sh.Name & "!" & _
                sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, lastCol), sh.Cells(i - 1, lastCol)).Address
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: .........nice idea...........populate a column with the collection and use the column for DV............... *(+1)*

Comment: @Gary's Student: Part of the credit must go tu you! My English is not enough accurate to understand the essence only reading the question. Your comment was the spark... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to *FaneDuru*'s excellent approach.  It uses a comma-separated string for the DV drop-down:

```
Sub CollectionToDV()
    Dim col As Collection, ci, DVstring As String

    Set col = New Collection
    col.Add "Larry"
    col.Add "Moe"
    col.Add "Curly"
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    DVstring = ""

    For Each ci In col
        DVstring = DVstring & IIf(DVstring = "", "", ",") & ci
    Next ci

    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=DVstring
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great and thank you for your help :) With a bit of tweaking and combining of what you two have done into one function with my original it is working :) One thing I would like it to do though is by using data validation for a drop down to run the macro instead of having to run it manually each time